# How come the NSA could release SELinux as GPL when all US Gov work must be Public Domain?

Tags: licensing, open-source, gpl, linux

*I'm not sure if this is a good question for this site, but it does deal with the things to do with working as programmer.*

SELinux is a security enhanced version of Linux, and was initially developed by the National Security Agency (NSA) of the USA. Since it's linked into the Linux kernel, it's available under the GNU GPL licence (right?).

However I thought that all work made by the US federal government had to be public domain (right?).

So how was the NSA able to legally produce something that's not PD, but instead GPL?

Comment: Because it's based on Linux, which is GPL?

Comment: Yes, I know the derived work of Linux must be GPL, but how were the NSA allowed to produce something that was a derived work of GPL? Surely the "PD only" rules means they should not legally be allowed produce/distribute it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FSF [answer this question themselves](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#GPLUSGovAdd):

> **Can the US Government release improvements to a GPL-covered program?**
>
> Yes. If the improvements are written by US government employees in the course of their employment, then the improvements are in the public domain. However, the improved version, as a whole, is still covered by the GNU GPL. There is no problem in this situation.

So the source code which is actually written by federal employees is in the public domain. You are free to do what you want with these components. But the rest is under the GPL, hence distribution of the work as a whole must comply with the GPL.